# Disabling download of php files if PHP is not installed

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My university has multiple servers which have the same data mirrored across them, so I can access for instance

```
foo.uni.edu/file.php
bar.uni.edu/file.php
```

The thing is, not all servers have PHP installed, so anyone could possibly download my php files if they made the connection through a server which didn't have PHP installed.
Is there a way, possibly with .htaccess to avoid this? As in, only allow opening PHP files if PHP server is installed?

Comment: You might be able to utilize `<IfModule !mod_php.c>`.

Comment: why not just restrict access to a single (load balancing) server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible to store files outside of the document root, you could work around the problem by storing all sensitive data outside the docroot. You would then have your publicly accessible scripts use `include` to access those files.

So, if you upload to `/username/public_html`, and `public_html` is your document root (eg, `foo.uni.edu/file.php` is `/username/public_html/file.php`), then you would upload to `/username/file.php` instead and place another script in `/username/public_html` which merely contains something like `include('../file.php');`

This is good practice in any case, in case a configuration error on the server ever stops PHP from being parsed.

You could also try using [`IfModule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ifmodule) and [`FilesMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch) to deny access to PHP files if `mod_php` isn't enabled:

```
<IfModule !mod_php.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from All
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

If this doesn't work, try `!mod_php5.c` instead.

Comment: Either of the mods gives permission denied error when trying to access a php file (in the server that has php installed)

Comment: Is it possible the servers are running an archaic PHP4 install? If so, try `!mod_php4.c`. If that doesn't work either, I'm afraid I'm stumped.